# facebook with action script 3 issue in retrieve friends

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, starling-framework, facebook-as3-api

I develop simple facebook game using action script 3 ,, I have an issue

-- first when I logged with Admin of the game or developer ,, I can get my profile and my friend list . and if I login to facebook with any user failed to retrieve user and friends O_O
 is that permission issue or what?

-- second issue I need to make my app ask for permission before loading swf ,, how can I do this?
my code:

```
    public function FaceBookData()
    {               
        Facebook.init(APP_ID, HandleFacebookConnect);                               
    }

    private function HandleFacebookConnect(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {           

        if(success)
        {           
            accessToken =params["access_token"] = Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken;   
            Facebook.api("v2.0/me/invitable_friends", RetrievedFriends, params);
            Facebook.api("v2.0/me", RetrievedMe, params);                   
        }
        else
        {               
            Facebook.login(HandleFacebookConnect,{perms: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'});
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "failed to retrieve" mean. Is there an error? Is there just an empty response? Please be specific. It's also better to make a question for each part as they are not related.

Comment: Failed to retrieve = empty response = not success ,, i'm very wonder  how success with developer and admin user and not success for other users ??